# Need to capture the file name from the directory path by looping the data file

Tags: linux, shell

I have the following data file.

```
recID#  Attachment#            Attachment#2.          ...... Attachment #15 
101      c:/a/b/c/d/fil1.txt    c:/a/b/c/d/e/aaa.txt   ...... c:/a/b/c/d/e/fff.txt        
103      c:/a/b/c/d/abc.txt     c:/a/b/c/d/e/bbb.txt   ...... c:/a/b/c/d/e/ggg.txt   
104      c:/a/b/c/d/e/efg.txt   c:/a/b/c/d/e/ccc.txt   ...... c:/a/b/c/d/e/hhh.txt   
105      c:/a/b/c/mnop.txt      c:/a/b/c/d/e/ddd.txt   ...... c:/a/b/c/d/e/iii.txt
```

I want to capture only the filename not the entire directory. below expected output.

```
rec ID#  Attachment1#         ttachment#2 ...... Attachment #15
101         fil1.txt            aaa.txt     ...... fff.txt      
103         abc.txt             bbb.txt     ...... ggg.txt  
104         efg.txt             ccc.txt     ...... hhh.txt  
105         mnop.txt            ddd.txt     ...... iii.txt
```

Also I want to compare each file in the local directory c:\a\b\c  available or not.
if available i want to create the /Test directory and move all the files which are available in that directory.

for ex: Attachment1 column the file name fil1.txt, if its available in this direcgtory "c:\a\b\c" then i want to copy the file from the directory "c:\a\b\c" to  "c:\a\b\d".

Thanks

Comment: Please check and [edit] your question and fix or explain the inconsistencies. In your example file you have `c:/a/b/c/d/fil1.txt`. In the text below the expected result you mention a `/Test` directory and later you mention that you want to check for `fil1.txt` in `c:\a\b\c` and copy from `c:\a\b\c` to `c:\a\b\d`. How is this related to ``c:/a/b/c/d/fil1.txt`?

Comment: Request your suggestion

Comment: Since you don't clarify your question as requested I can only answer how to create an output file that lists the file names without a directory.

Comment: No Luck. the given command <BR> sed 's#[^ \t]*/##g' inputfile > outputfile  <BR> Or <BR> awk '{gsub(/[^ \t]*\//,"",$0);print}' inputfile > outputfile
 Not working .. writing the same file again

Comment: Here I have provided the Input file (CSV) and expected output file (CSV). not sure what else need to provide you. Thanks!

Comment: Your comment "No Luck..." seems to be related to my answer. The next time you should add it to the answer instead of to your question. As I wrote in the answer, I tested my commands with your input. Did you test with the example from your question or with a different input file? Does your real input file contain `\` instead of `/`?

Comment: Regarding the clarification: Input and output file are mostly clear. It is not clear if the columns of your input are separated by spaces or tabs. You didn't specify how the columns of the output should be separated. Do you want to keep the separation from the input? Do you want nicely aligned columns? Do you want exactly one tab?

Comment: For me it is also not clear how  `c:\a\b\c` and `c:\a\b\d` in the text below the output are related to `c:/a/b/c/d/fil1.txt` from your input file. Possible interpretations: You always want to copy the file from `c:\a\b\c` and `c:\a\b\d` regardless of what directory is specified in the input. Or the source and destination directories are derived from the directory specified in the input file. Or a typo in your input or explanation. Please explain (or fix) this in your question. Using a few different examples might be more clear, e.g. also for   `c:/a/b/c/d/e/efg.txt` and `c:/a/b/c/mnop.txt`.

Comment: As I can no longer edit my comment, I repeat and fix my question here: Does your real input file contain a backslash `\ ` instead of a forward slash `/`?

Answer (score 0):

To remove the directory part from all file names you could use

```
sed 's#[^ \t]*/##g' inputfile > outputfile
```

or

```
awk '{gsub(/[^ \t]*\//,"",$0);print}' inputfile > outputfile
```

From the sample input file in the question I get this output

```
recID#  Attachment#            Attachment#2.          ...... Attachment #15 
101      fil1.txt    aaa.txt   ...... fff.txt        
103      abc.txt     bbb.txt   ...... ggg.txt   
104      efg.txt   ccc.txt   ...... hhh.txt   
105      mnop.txt      ddd.txt   ...... iii.txt
```

If the formatting of the output is important, please specify in the question what requirements you have.

As it is not clear from the question how the directories where to check for files or where to move files from/to are related to the input file, I cannot answer the other part of the question.

**Edit:**

In case the real input contains backslashes (`\`) instead of forward slashes (`/`), the following modified commands use `[/\\]` instead of `/` or `\/` to make them work with both input variants:

```
sed 's#[^ \t]*[/\\]##g' inputfile > outputfile
awk '{gsub(/[^ \t]*[/\\]/,"",$0);print}' inputfile > outputfile
```

Comment: One easy way to "fix" the output formatting would be to pipe the result of the `sed`/`awk` call to `column -t` (assuming the OP is ok with space-separated columns, that is ...)

Comment: @AdminBee I didn't care because there is no information about this in the question and it is not clear if the headings or file names can contain spaces. (`Attachment #15` would result in an additional column.)